# How do I make the substitution ? Scheme

Tags: scheme

How do I make the substitution? I tried to trace but I don't really get what is going on...
the code:

```
(define (repeated f n)
  (if (zero? n)
    identity
    (lambda (x) ((repeated f (- n 1)) (f x)))))
```

f is a function and n is an integer that gives the number of times we should apply f.
....can someone help me to interpret it. I know it returns several procedures and i want to believe that it goes `f(f(f(x)))`

okey i will re-ask this question but in different manner, because i didn't really get an answer last time. consider this code

```
(define (repeated f n)
  (if (zero? n)
    identity
    (lambda (x) ((repeated f (- n 1)) (f x)))))
```

where n is a positive integer and f is an arbitrary function: how does scheme operate on this code lets say we give `(repeated f 2)`. what will happen? this is what think:

```
(f 2)

(lambda (x) ((repeated f (- 2 1)) (f x))))


(f 1)

(lambda (x) ((lambda (x) ((repeated f (- 1 1)) (f x)))) (f x))))


(f 0)
```

### (lambda (x) ((lambda (x) (identity (f x)))) (f x))))

```
> (lambda (x) ((lambda (x) (identity (f x)))) (f x))))

>  (lambda (x) ((lambda (x) ((f x)))) (f x))))
```

here is were i get stuck first i want it to go (f(f(x))  but now i will get (lambda x ((f x) (f x)) , the parentheses is certaintly wrong , but i think you understand what i mean. What is wrong with my arguments on how the interpreter works

Answer (score 2):

You've got a function that takes a function `f` and an non-negative integer `n` and returns the function *f<sup>n</sup>*, i.e., *f(f(f(…f(n)…)*.  Depending on how you think of your recursion, this could be implemented straightforwardly in either of two ways.  In both cases, if *n* is 0, then you just need a function that returns its argument, and that function is the `identity` function.  (This is sort of by convention, in the same way that x<sup>0</sup> = 1.  It does make sense when it's considered in more depth, but that's probably out of scope for this question.)

How you handle the recursive case is where you have some options.  The first option is to think of *f<sup>n</sup>(x)* as *f(f<sup>n-1</sup>(x))*, where you call *f*  with the result of calling *f<sup>n-1</sup>* with *x*:

```
(define (repeated f n)
  (if (zero? n)
      identity
      (lambda (x)
        (f ((repeated f (- n 1)) x)))))
```

The other option is to think of *f<sup>n</sup>(x)* as *f<sup>n-1</sup>(f(x))* where _f<sup>n-1</sup> gets called with the result of *f(x)*.

```
(define (repeated f n)
  (if (zero? n)
      identity
      (lambda (x)
        ((repeated f (- n 1)) (f x)))))
```

In either case, the important thing to note here is that in Scheme, a form like

```
(function-form arg-form-1 arg-form-2 ...)
```

is evaluated by evaluating `function-form` to produce a value *function-value* (which should be a function) and evaluating each `arg-form-i` to produce values *arg-value-i*, and then *calling* _function-value_ with the *arg-values*.  Since `(repeated ...)` produces a function, it's suitable as a `function-form`:

```
 (f ((repeated f (- n 1)) x))
;    |--- f^{n-1} ------| 
;   |---- f^{n-1}(x) ------|
;|------f(f^{n-1}(x)) ------|

 ((repeated f (- n 1)) (f x))
; |--- f^{n-1} ------|
;|---- f^{n-1}(f(x))--------|
```

Based on Will Ness's comment, it's worth pointing out that while these are somewhat natural ways to decompose this problem (i.e., based on the equalities f<sup>n</sup>(x) = f<sup>n-1</sup>(f(x)) = f(f<sup>n-1</sup>(x))), it's not necessarily the most efficient.  These solutions both require computing some intermediate function objects to represent f<sup>n-1</sup> that require a fair amount of storage, and then some computation on top of that.  Computing f<sup>n</sup>(x) directly is pretty straightforward and efficient with, e.g., `repeat`:

```
(define (repeat f n x)
  (let rep ((n n) (x x))
    (if (<= n 0)
        x
        (rep (- n 1) (f x)))))
```

A more efficient version of `repeated`, then, simply curries the `x` argument of `repeat`:

```
(define (repeated f n)
  (lambda (x) 
    (repeat f n x)))
```

This should have better run time performance than either of the other implementations.

Comment: AFAIK his code is working properly, he just wants to know how.

Comment: @uselpa Oops, you're right. I'll edit so it doesn't sound like OP's code is broken.

Comment: but the two options lead to different run time behaviour.

Comment: @WillNess You got me thinking about this… Yes, the two do have different run time behavior, because they are different code.  However, I don't think there should be much _noticeable_ behavior in most regards (e.g., how long they take to run).  In both cases, a lambda function is returned that delays any further computation.  When computation actually occurs, `(repeated f (- n 1))` has to be computed in both cases, and so does an additional single call to `f`.  If `f` is a pure function (i.e., doesn't have any sneaky side effects, etc.), then the results should be the same.

Comment: @WillNess  All that was to say that both are commputing {f^n}(x).  I certainly could have missed something, though.  Do you have a particular case in mind?

Comment: It's just that the first looked more nested to me, and the second more flat. But it's just an impression; I didn't check it fully. Or I might be completely wrong. :) It's better to have a flat execution (i.e., minimal stack usage) of course. That's why I didn't initially upvote.

Comment: @WillNess You make a very good point about this not being the most efficient way to return the function {f^n}.  It's straightforward to _compute_ {f^n}(x) using an accumulator and tail recursion, and the most efficient way to get the function {f^n} is just to curry the argument x.  (And I think this is the point that you were making in [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19377839/1281433).)  I've updated my answer to show such an implementation, and noted that it should be more efficient than the others (in both time and space).

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation actually delays the further recursion and return a procedure whose body will create copies of itself to fulfill the task at runtime.

Eg. `(repeated double 4)` ==> `(lambda (x) ((repeated double (- 4 1)) (double x)))`
So when calling it `((repeated double 4) 2)` it runs `((repeated double (- 4 1)) (double 2)))`
where the operand part evaluates to `(lambda (x) ((repeated double (- 3 1)) (double x)))` and so on making the closures at run time so the evaluation becomes equal to this, but in stages during runtime..

```
((lambda (x) ((lambda (x) ((lambda (x) ((lambda (x) ((lambda (x) (identity x)) (double x))) (double x))) (double x))) (double x))) 2)
```

A different way of writing the same functionality would be like this:

```
(define (repeat fun n)
  (lambda (x)
    (let repeat-loop ((n n)
                      (x x))
      (if (<= n 0) 
          x
          (repeat-loop (- n 1) (fun x))))))

(define (double x) (+ x x))
((repeat double 4) 2) ; ==> 32
```

Answer (score 0):

Danny. I think that if we work `repeated` with small values of n (0, 1 and 2) will be able to see how the function translates to f(f(f(...(x))). I assume that `identity`'s implementation is `(define (identity x) x)` (i.e. returns its only parameter as is), and that the "then" part of the `if` should be `(identity f)`.

```
(repeated f 0) ;should apply f only once, no repetition
-> (identity f)
-> f

(repeated f 1) ;expected result is f(f(x))
-> (lambda (x) ((repeated f 0) (f x)))
-> (lambda (x) (f (f x))) ;we already know that (repeated f 0) is f

(repeated f 2) ;expected result is f(f(f(x)))
-> (lambda (x) ((repeated f 1) (f x)))
-> (lambda (x) (f (f (f x)))) ; we already know that (repeated f 1) if f(f(x))
```

... and so on.

Comment: (lambda (x) ((repeated f 1) (f x))) , so if you interchange  (f 1)  to f(f(x)) , you get; (lambda (x) (f(f(x)) (f x)))   i dont really get how it becomes (lambda (x) (f (f (f x)))) ,

Comment: `(repeated f 0)` is `identity`, not `(identity f)`.

Answer (score 0):

Equational reasoning would be very helpful here. Imagine [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus)-based language with Haskell-like syntax, practically a [combinatory calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus).

Here, parentheses are used just for grouping of expressions (not for function calls, which have no syntax at all – just juxtaposition): `f a b c` is the same as `((f a) b) c`, the same as Scheme's `(((f a) b) c)`. Definitions like  `f a b = ...` are equivalent to  `(define f (lambda (a) (lambda (b) ...)))` (and shortcut for `(lambda (a) ...)` is `(\a-> ...)`.

Scheme's syntax just obscures the picture here. I don't mean parentheses, but being forced to explicit lambdas instead of just equations and freely shifting the arguments around:

```
f a b = \c -> ....   ===   f a b c = ....      ; `\ ->` is for 'lambda'
```

Your code is then nearly equivalent to

```
repeated f n x                          ; (define (repeated f n)
  | n <= 0    = x                       ;  (if (zero? n)  identity
  | otherwise = repeated f (n-1) (f x)  ;    (lambda (x)
                                        ;      ((repeated f (- n 1)) (f x)))))
```

(read `|` as "when"). So

```
  repeated f 2 x =     ; ((repeated f 2) x) = ((\x-> ((repeated f 1) (f x))) x)
= repeated f 1 (f x)       ;      = ((repeated f 1) (f x))
= repeated f 0 (f (f x))   ;      = ((\y->((repeated f 0) (f y))) (f x))
= f (f x)                  ;      = ((\z-> z) (f (f x)))
                           ;      = (f (f x))
```

The above reduction sequence leaves out the particulars of environment frames creation and chaining in Scheme, but it all works out pretty much intuitively. `f` is the same `f`, `n-1 where n=2` is `1` no matter *when* we perform the subtraction, etc..